# Is there any difference between blocking and non blocking send

Tags: c, linux, tcp

If the application can ensure that there would always be space in the socket's send buffer, would blocking and non blocking send have same performance? In this scenario, is there any advantages in either approach over the other?

Comment: why don't you implement both, and run some tests?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The system already provides you with a way of doing the job for you.

Comment: @xiaoyi - There are many, many code paths through the kernel that a simple test program might not exercise.  It is a valid question and "just try it" is not a useful response.

Comment: @Nemo but if it is that complicated how can one answer this question?

Comment: @xiaoyi The question is about 'advantages', not performance. There are other kinds of advantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between blocking and non-blocking `send` is whether the kernel puts your process to sleep or returns `EWOULDBLOCK`.  So in terms of performance, there should be no difference.

However, I doubt your implicit assumption that the send cannot block just because the send buffer has free space.  Imagine an idle socket on a system that places heavy demands on memory.  I would not necessarily expect the kernel to "pin" the physical pages for your send buffer; I would expect it to use that memory for something useful instead.  And then when you try to send, the kernel will need to grab a free page for the send buffer; and if there are no such pages available, it might decide to return `EWOULDBLOCK` instead of waiting on (say) swap.

Now, that is a lot of "maybes" and "mights", and someone more familiar with the kernel's internals could tell me I am wrong.  But even if Linux does not behave this way today, it might tomorrow; and are you 100% sure you will never run your application on anything other than Linux, ever?

So I would not write my application with such a fragile assumption.  I suggest you decide whether blocking or non-blocking semantics make more sense for your own code, and do not try to game the kernel's internals.

[Update]

I was hoping I would not have to dig in to Linux internals, but an overconfident downvoter has driven me to it.

Start with [net/ipv4/tcp.c at the "new_segment" label](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.9/net/ipv4/tcp.c#L864):

```
new_segment:
if (!sk_stream_memory_free(sk))
    goto wait_for_sndbuf;

skb = sk_stream_alloc_skb(sk, 0, sk->sk_allocation);
if (!skb)
    goto wait_for_memory;
```

See how "wait_for_sndbuf" is distinct from "wait_for_memory"?  That is what I am talking about.

At the "wait_for_memory" label, there is a call to [`sk_stream_wait_memory`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.9/net/core/stream.c#L117) with a `timeo` value that depends on whether this is a non-blocking send.  That function, in turn, either puts the process to sleep or returns `EAGAIN` depending on `timeo`.

[Update 2]

Just to be clear what question I am answering...

I interpret this question to be, "If I know that my socket's send buffer has sufficient free space, is there any difference -- performance or otherwise -- between a blocking and a non-blocking `send` on that socket?"

The premise is certainly possible if, for example, your protocol is to send one message, and then only send a new message after receiving a reply to a previous message.  In this case, you know the send buffer is always empty when you `send`.  By getting and/or setting the POSIX-standard `SO_SNDBUF` socket option, you can know that your socket has adequate free space.  In this case, can a blocking `send` behave differently from a non-blocking `send`?

My reading of the POSIX spec says "yes" in principle.  My reading of the Linux source code says "yes" in practice.  I could certainly be wrong, but it would take someone more knowledgeable about POSIX or Linux to demonstrate it, and none of them have answered this question so far.

[Final (?) update]

Here is what I believe POSIX allows/requires you to assume.

If there is adequate free space in the send buffer, then a blocking `send` cannot block forever.  This is the same sense in which a call to `calloc` with adequate free virtual memory cannot block forever.  Eventually the system will find the resources it needs to send your data.

(Note the same is not true when the send buffer is full, in which case a blocking `send` might block forever depending on what is happening at the receiving end of the socket.)

However, even when there is adequate space in the send buffer, a non-blocking `send` might still return `EWOULDBLOCK`.  So if you use non-blocking sockets, your code must handle this regardless of what you know about the send buffer or anything else.

Comment: You are speculating wildly about the send buffer. It is allocated permanently on creation of the socket and it is required to persist between send() calls by the semantics of TCP. That is what it is *for.*. DV

Comment: @EJP - OK I stopped speculating and added references to the kernel source.  Please either remove your downvote or demonstrate that this code path is impossible.

Comment: Nemo, certainly, your update 2 reflects my usecase, where there is only one unacknowledged message at time. The message sizes are between 1K - 3KB. So, a 4KB SO_SNDBUF is allocated. In cases, where adequate memory is available, is there any other difference ?

Comment: @Jimm, I have updated by answer again.  Note that the right question is not, "what does Linux happen to do today?" but rather "what shoul I assume if I want my code to run today and tomorrow?"

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that you cannot always be sure your send will be executed rapidly.

For instance, if the socket on the other side is not read using recv, your buffer will be full.

Of course, if you write both sides of the application and always read, there would not be a significant difference concerning performance i guess.

Comment: You have overlooked part of the question. Specifically, the part starting 'If the application can ensure ...'. The first five words.

Comment: It is not stated that "The application" is also responsible of reading on the socket is it ?

Comment: It is stated as an assumption in the first sentence that the application can ensure there is room in the send buffer. The relevance of your question escapes me.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you can 'ensure that there would always be room in the socket send buffer' is by not sending when it is full.

You can indeed determine whether there is room in the send buffer - on some systems. If there isn't room in blocking mode, you can select() for writability - on some systems. On other systems you can't tell whether there is room and/or you can't select() in blocking mode.

On such systems you don't have any good implementation choices except to send and block, or else use blocking mode.

On the systems where you can know but not select(), you can loop and sleep, but you can't know how long to sleep for, so you will sleep for too long and waste time, unlike blocking, which will block for exactly the right length of time.

Comment: -1.  Cite the POSIX spec (or Linux source code) showing that writes to a socket with room in the send buffer cannot have different behavior for blocking/non-blocking sockets, and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Nemo Suppose *you* cite where I have said that it can't?

Comment: The question was, "is there any difference between blocking and non-blocking send?" (when it is known that there is space in the send buffer).  I interpret your answer to be "no", which is wrong.  Did you intend it to be "yes"?

Comment: @Nemo How you can 'interpret' all that as a simple 'no' is a mystery to me. I am addressing the premisses of his question, and the reasons why they are invalid in blocking mode. I haven't said a word about non-blocking mode. This is thoroughly ridiculous.

Comment: He is asking a straightforward question.  He titled it very precisely and explained it in detail.  I interpret your answer to his question to be "no" plus a bunch of commentary.  (If you only want to provide commentary, you should do so in the comments.)  Your commentary is valid, but your answer to his question is wrong.  If you make it clear that your answer to his question is "yes", I will remove my downvote.  Pretty simple, actually.

Comment: @Nemo Your wild misinterpretation deserves a downvote of its own. The difference he is asking about is that one part of it doesn't really exist in any useful form, and *that* is my answer. Pretty simple really.

Comment: Well, you are wrong about that, too.  It is certainly possible to know that your send buffer has room on *all* systems.  For example, your code might only send a TCP message after it receives a reply to the previous message.  In that case, you know the send buffer is always empty; and by setting the `SO_SNDBUF` socket option, you know how much free space it has.  Even in this case, though, blocking and non-blocking sockets can behave differently when the system is under memory pressure.

Comment: @Nemo I don't know the behaviour of the OP's system, and neither do you. Obviously I am referring to the availability or otherwise of system calls to tell you the current state of the send buffer. When you've finished putting words into the OP's mouth, and mine, and when you've finished with your wilful misinterpretations of what I wrote, and confronted the fact that I didn't write what you said I wrote, which is all you advanced as the justification for your downvote, and that I am not here providing a yes/no answer at all, we might get somewhere.

Comment: 1) I know the exact behavior of the OP's system because it is tagged "linux" and I read the source. 2) I quoted the OP's exact words, and judging by his comments on my answer (have you read it?), I interpreted him correctly. 3) I generously assumed that in addition to blathering uselessly you were trying to provide an answer to the question.  Now you say you were not; fair enough, my mistake.  But also a valid reason to downvote.  When you _answer the question_ and _answer correctly_ I will remove my DV.  Nothing personal.